# Problems to charge Json to my Android App, JSONException

Tags: android, json, jsonexception

I have trying to connect a application to web services that retrieves a JSON, but return JSONException

My code:

```
private class LlenarDatosReproduccion extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Ups! Error.Parece que la url es inválida";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            JSONArray cancionJSON = responseJSON.getJSONArray("cancion");
            tvTitle.setText(cancionJSON.getString(1));
            //tvArtist.setText(cancionJSON.getString(2));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Please look the Logcat image

[image]

Comment: Couls you post the json response .?

Comment: what are oyu doing with downloadUrl and returnning ??à

Comment: here https://pruebasmartunes.000webhostapp.com/pruebas_getMp3StreamTitle.php

Comment: put your response here and the code where you parsing

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that exception because the JSON you are attempting to parse does not have an array field called "cancion". I can't see the whole JSON in the logcat image you linked (next time, you're better off including the text in your question rather than a screenshot), from what I can see, the field names are in English not Spanish and none of the visible fields are arrays.

Now that you included the whole JSON: I can see that cancion is a JSONObject not a JSONArray.

Comment: what a shame i'm pretty newbie. Look at the JSON structure onthis link: https://pruebasmartunes.000webhostapp.com/pruebas_getMp3StreamTitle.php

Comment: {"cancion":{"title":"Versace On The Floor (Vs David Guetta)","artist":"BRUNO MARS","duration":"18783"}}

Comment: edited my response. "cancion" is a JsonObject, not an array.

Comment: Thaks, Chris... I could do it...!!